# ¿Como crear un proceso que se ejecute diariamente usando C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Lo que pasa es que tengo que generar un reporte diariamente a partir de unos datos obtenidos de la BD. Ya genero el reporte y lo envío por correo a partir de un botón, ahora la aplicación se va alojar en un servidor, entonces se requiere que una vez que se ejecute y se envié el reporte, espere 24 hrs y vuelva a enviar el reporte de manera automática, es decir sin que alguien tenga que entrar al servidor y presionar nuevamente el botón para que se vuelva a enviar.(Alguna idea de como hacerlo?)

---

es un WindowsForm el cual se va alojar en un servidor por lo que estará en ejecución todo el tiempo.

Comment: Tu desarrollo es winforms, webforms, wpf, silverligth?

Comment: es un WindowsForm el cual se va alojar en un servidor por lo que estará en ejecución todo el tiempo.

Comment: Si tienes claro como hacer el primer paso, esto es la parte de generar el fichero y enviarlo por correo, solo tendrás que crear en el nuevo servidor una tarea programada, diaria a una determinada hora, para que el solo se pueda ejeutar

Answer (score 1):

Definitivamente esa no es la mejor forma de proceder con una tarea recurrente.

Si no tienes de otra tu primera opcion es crear una tarea en el administrador de tareas de windows y elegir el ejecutable que realizara la acción, pero ese ejecutable tendrá que realizar la acción del click del botón automáticamente al abrirlo.

Una buena opción es usar [SSIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) para generar un paquete que sea ejecutado cada cierto tiempo por un job mas en forma en tu server y ahí tendrás mas flexibilidad también para extraer datos de la base, transformarlos y generar notificaciones en un ambiente mucho mas estable y robusto.

Otra alternativa open source es [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) que te permite realizar las mismas tareas que el anterior pero sin pagar un centavo.

Espero que te sean de ayuda mis comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

nosotros lo resolvimos de la siguiente forma:

Desarrollamos un programa de consola que genera varios reportes y los envía por email dependiendo de los parámetros que recibe como argumentos. [Ver más](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-MX/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Inicialmente usabamos Windows Forms, pero frecuentemente se quedaba colgado; además que el programa de consola usa menos recursos y se ejecuta más rápido.

Para mandar llamar el programa utilizamos el Programador de Tareas de Windows, esta herramienta por si misma te permite configurar los parámetros que deseas enviar, los horarios de ejecución, frecuencia de ejecución, te permite ejecutar l programa al prender la computadora, que se encontrara apagada a la hora que debía ejecutarse, y muchas otras funciones útiles, te lo recomiendo.

Si necesitas mas detalles házmelo saber.

Suerte

[Como abrir el programador de Tareas en diferentes versiones de Windows (inglés)](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard)

[Uso del programador de tareas (Video en español)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-Lq1IwGaxE).

Comment: Ok, gracias por el dato...

Answer (score 1):

Creando un Windows Service con un `Timer` de 24 horas de ejecución, es decir, que se ejecute el método que genera los reportes.

Este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/best-timer-for-using-in-a-windows-service) proporciona toda la información necesaria para que puedas crear el proyecto y ejecutar los métodos necesarios.

Es decir, ahora tendrás dos modos para obtener el reporte, uno por medio del botón y otro por medio de la tarea automática del Servicio de Windows.

Answer (score 0):

El método ideal para esto resolver esta tarea es la creación de un Servicio de Windows, aquí te dejo información teórica sobre esto [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx), y como instalar el Servicio de Windows en el servidor [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/sd8zc8ha(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 60000; // 60 seconds
timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Para no tener que modificar el código en la aplicación, podrías crear un servicio de integración (Integration Services Project SSIS),  y lo ejecutas en el agente de sql server, de esa forma tendría un acceso a los datos más seguro, [Aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbC_ronWGXo) puedes encontrar mayor información.

Answer (score 0):

Dejo una solucion al problema desde el enfoque de *servicio windows*, que es el ejemplo que falta.

Esta es una implementación de un servicio windows que corre una tarea planificada (muestra la hora cada 15 seg. por consola) con la librería Quartz que me parece bastante poderosa para planificar tareas.

En el código fui dejando las referencias externas que fui tomando en el código para hacerlo lo más sencillo posible.

- Program.cs (Punto de entrada de la aplicación)[1]

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Reflection;
  using System.ServiceProcess;
  using System.Threading;

  namespace ServicioDiario
  {
      /*
       * El ejemplo se basa en una forma para depurar servicios windows de manera simple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125964/easier-way-to-debug-a-windows-service
       */
      static class Program
      {
          /// <summary>
          /// The main entry point for the application.
          /// </summary>
          static void Main()
          {
              ServiceBase[] servicesToRun;
              servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
              {
                  new Service1()
              };

              if (Environment.UserInteractive)
              {
                  RunInteractive(servicesToRun);
              }
              else
              {
                  ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
              }
          }

          static void RunInteractive(ServiceBase[] servicesToRun)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("* El servicio esta corriendo en modo interactivo *");
              Console.WriteLine();

              MethodInfo onStartMethod = typeof(ServiceBase).GetMethod("OnStart",
                  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
              foreach (ServiceBase service in servicesToRun)
              {
                  Console.Write("Iniciando servicio {0}...", service.ServiceName);
                  onStartMethod.Invoke(service, new object[] { new string[] { } });
                  Console.Write("Iniciado");
              }

              Console.WriteLine();
              Console.WriteLine(
                  "Presione una tecla para detener el servicio y el proceso...");
              Console.ReadKey();
              Console.WriteLine();

              MethodInfo onStopMethod = typeof(ServiceBase).GetMethod("OnStop",
                  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
              foreach (ServiceBase service in servicesToRun)
              {
                  Console.Write("Deteniendo {0}...", service.ServiceName);
                  onStopMethod.Invoke(service, null);
                  Console.WriteLine("Detenido");
              }

              Console.WriteLine("Todos los servicios planificado estan detenidos.");
              // Permanezco un segundo para que pueda ver el mensaje.
              Thread.Sleep(1000);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Trabajo.cs (Clase que va a realizar el trabajo sucio)[3]

  ```
  using System;
  using Quartz;

  namespace ServicioDiario
  {
      /*
       * Libreria recomendada para planificacion
       * https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/
       */
      public class Trabajo : IJob
      {
          public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
          {
              //Realizar la tarea planificada.
              System.Console.WriteLine("Hora: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Planificador.cs (Clase que sirve para manipular el inicio y el final de la planificación)

  ```
  using Quartz;
  using Quartz.Impl;

  namespace ServicioDiario
  {
      public class Planificador
      {
          public void Iniciar()
          {
              IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
              scheduler.Start();

              IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<Trabajo>().Build();
              //Cada 15 segundos
              ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                     .WithSimpleSchedule(a => a.WithIntervalInSeconds(15).RepeatForever())
                     .Build();

              // Cada un dia
              //ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
              //       .WithSimpleSchedule(a => a.WithIntervalInHours(24).RepeatForever())
              //       .Build();

              scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
          }

          public void Detener()
          {
              IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
              scheduler.Shutdown();
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Service1.cs (servicio que se crea por defecto con la plantilla de servicio windows) [4]

  ```
      using System.ServiceProcess;

  namespace ServicioDiario
  {
      /*
       * Codigo fuente basado en el siguiente enlace en ingles: http://www.codingdefined.com/2016/08/schedule-tasks-as-windows-service-using.html
       */
      public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
      {
          Planificador plan;

          public Service1()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
          }

          protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
          {
              plan = new Planificador();
              plan.Iniciar();
          }

          protected override void OnStop()
          {
              if (plan != null)
              {
                  plan.Detener();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Nota: En este ejemplo es necesario cambiar el tipo de aplicacion a consola para que pueda mostrar los resultados y hacer las pruebas[2].

Como observación final: existe todo un debate sobre utilizar el programador de tareas, un timer o un servicio windows.
En mi experiencia el uso depende de cuanto control y que seguimiento debas hacer a la/s tarea/s.
Mientras más tareas, relacionadas a una applicacion, debas planificar con diferentes periodos de ejecución y mayor control el enfoque de servicio de windows es mejor.

---

Referencias:

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125964/easier-way-to-debug-a-windows-service

[2] https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/s3awkzkh(v=vs.100).aspx

[3] https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

[4] http://www.codingdefined.com/2016/08/schedule-tasks-as-windows-service-using.html